# text align right relatively to parent G in SVG

Tags: javascript, css, xml, svg, d3.js

I want to create SVG tooltip but I when I want align text to right I have a problem.

```
<g class="svgTootlip">
    <rect class="ttip" x="-100" y="-50" width="100" height="50" rx="2" ry="2"></rect>
    <text x="-90" y="-40">
        4 Dec 2014
    </text>
</g>
```

This group (`d3TtipG`) is a part of bigger SVG file and is transformed depends of the mouse position.

JS:

```
d3Container.on('mousemove', function () {
    cords = d3.mouse(this);
    tr_x = cords[0];
    tr_y = cords[1];
    if (tr_x > 23 && tr_y > 23) {
        ...
        d3TtipG.attr({
            style: 'transform: translate(' + ((tr_x < 560) ? tr_x + 110 : tr_x - 15) + 'px, ' + ((tr_y < 215) ? tr_y + 55 : tr_y - 10) + 'px)'
        });
    } else {
        hideViewFinder();
    }
});
```

Is there a cross browser way to force this text to stick on the right side of `rect` or `g` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

set the x position of the text to the rect x + width and set `text-anchor="end"`